# SQL split string and insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I am looking for some guidance for the problem below.

I have a table with two columns `OP_ID` and `value`.

The value column is string that has two delimiters in it a comma and for the end of the line a hash.

The current table is called `Torque`.

| OP_ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 930823 | 1,0.45,0.5,0.55,N.m.#2,0.25,0.3,0.35,N.m.# |
| 930824 | 1,0.45,0.5,0.55,N.m.# |

And the desired output into table called Torque2

```
  OP_ID   | Tool | R_lower_lim | R_nominal_torque| R_Upper_lim | units
----------|------|-------------|------------------|------------|--------
  930823  | 1    | 0.45        | 0.5              | 0.55       | N.m.
  930823  | 2    | 0.25        | 0.3              | 0.35       | N.m.
  930824  | 1    | 0.45        | 0.5              | 0.55       | N.m.
```

I have not entered any code into the question because all of my attempts have been no where near the desired result.

Many thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably use product specific functions.)

Comment: Hi I am using MS SQL server management studio on version 14.0.2027.2 sql express.

Comment: Probably need a procedure that parses string to array or collection and writes records to table. I could easily do this in Access VBA but no idea how to program for SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big string-split and re-aggregation problem.  The following assumes that `row_number() over order by (select NULL))` returns the correct sequential number.

This tends to be true in practice, but Microsoft has not confirmed in the documentation that it is always true.  I should reference this:  Aaron Bertrand claims that this is true ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741625/extract-strings-till-the-second-delim-sql/65742026#65742026)).  I am uncomfortable relying on undocumented features, but in this case, the alternative is a sort that would fail if there are duplicate values.

```
select t.*, s.value, s2.*
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.value, '#') s cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then s2.value end) as Tool,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then s2.value end) as R_lower_lim,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then s2.value end) as R_nominal_torque,
             max(case when seqnum = 4 then s2.value end) as R_Upper_lim,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then s2.value end) as units
      from (select s2.value,
                   row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
            from string_split(s.value, ',') s2
           ) s2
     ) s2
where s.value <> '';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=59d86b3008a43f7235ae846688f7ada1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: MS has documented that there is [no guarantee](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - _"The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed ..."_ And surely you know that your order-by-null kludge is equally problematic.

Comment: @SMor . . . I added the reference and some more verbiage.  I'm quite reluctant to depend on undocumented features.  But the alternative seems a bit worse because it precludes duplicated values across columns.